# Android SDK - Detect physical location of front-facing camera

Tags: android, android-camera

The "normal" place for a front facing camera is to be on the top of the device when holding it in portrait (display taller than wide).  The camera, when it is on top, is usually in near the middle, but not always.  Sometimes it is in the corner.

There are also other devices (mostly tablets) where the hardware manufacturer has places the camera on the side when holding the device in portrait.  For instance, the Lenovo Tab 10 ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MR3FS4F/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MR3FS4F)).

Some device manufactures have even placed the camera on the bottom.

Is there a way with the Android SDK to determine the "physical location" of the camera as described above?

Comment: This would be awesome! I'm not aware of anything though, sorry!

Comment: Check [ameraCharacteristics.LENS_POSE_TRANSLATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_POSE_TRANSLATION), it's pretty awesome, but not exactly what you are asking for.